# What is the relationship between $a$ and $m$

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, visible-light

$a$ is defined in [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Orbits_of_test_particles)

What is the relationship between the length-scale $a$ and the mass $m$?

Comment: Please don't define stuff with *links*, include the definition (and a bit more context) into the question.

Comment: (Adding to the above comment) ... especially when $a$ happens to be what it is, in the "HERE" link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Schutz](http://www.amazon.co.uk/First-Course-General-Relativity/dp/0521887054) (chapter 11) for the Schwarzschild metric $dr/d\phi$ is given by:

$$ \left(\frac{dr}{d\phi}\right)^2 = \frac{E^2}{L^2}r^4 - \left(1 - \frac{r_s}{r}\right)\left(\frac{r^4}{L^2} + r^2\right) $$

where:

$$\begin{align}
E &= \frac{p_0}{m} \\
L &= \frac{p_\phi}{m}
\end{align}$$

Comparing this with the equation in the Wikipedia article we find:

$$ a = L = \frac{p_\phi}{m} = r^2\frac{p^\phi}{m} $$

Though this makes $a$ an angular velocity rather than a length scale.

Comment: thanks, John, this is really help?