# Why is $p_\phi$ conserved in a Schwarzschild orbit?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, conservation-laws, symmetry, geodesics

This arises from the question [What is the relationship between $a$ and $m$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/175070/what-is-the-relationship-between-a-and-m), which I'm afraid I answered just by looking it up in [Schutz's book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/First-Course-General-Relativity/dp/0521887054). However Schutz (as he frequently does) glosses over details he thinks are irrelevant or too simple to be worth explaining, and I have realised I don't understand an assumption he makes.

Schutz states without proof that if we have an equatorial orbit in a Schwartzschild metric then:

> Independence of the metric of the angle $\phi$ about the axis implies that $p_\phi$ is constant.

In the non-relativistic world I assume this corresponds to angular momentum being constant in a central potential. So far so good. But why is it the component of the dual vector $p_\phi$ that is constant rather than $p^\phi$? The component $p^\phi$ is presumably not constant since (in this case) $p^\phi = p_\phi/r^2$.

Bonus points for also explaining his similar claim that time independance means that $p_t$ is constant rather than $p^t$.

I fear that Schutz didn't explain because it's an insultingly simple question, but if someone can provide a nice intuitive explanation I would be very pleased to read it.

Comment: Thanks to both Alfred and Prahar. Both answers are really helpful. I've accepted Alfred's over Prahar's only because reading the bit of Schutz Alfred pointed me to has been particularly helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But why is it the component of the dual vector $p_\phi$ that is constant
>   rather than $p^\phi$?

From the bottom of page 189:

> The geodesic equation can thus, in complete generality, be written
>
> $$m \frac{dp_\beta}{d\tau} = \frac{1}{2}g_{\nu \alpha,\beta}\;p^\nu
>  p^\alpha$$
>
> We therefore have the following important result:  *if all of the
>   components $g_{\mu \nu}$ are independent of $x^\beta$ for some fixed
>   index $\beta$, then $p_\beta$ is a constant along any particle's
>   trajectory*

Also, be aware that, in the relevant section on equatorial orbits in the Schwarzschild geometry, Schutz is working in a *coordinate* basis and not a *unit* basis.

In the case that $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ (as in this example), we have

$$\vec e_\phi \cdot \vec e_\phi = r^2$$

which is why, I believe, $p^\phi$ is $r$ dependent.

Comment: Aha, thanks, I'll go away and read, learn and inwardly digest.

Comment: @JohnRennie, thanks for asking this question.  I almost always enjoy looking through my well worn copy of Schutz's book which was a Christmas gift from many years ago.  The discussion of coordinate basis versus unit basis is on pages 144 - 147.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\xi^\alpha$ be a Killing vector of a metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, i.e. it satisfies
$$
\nabla_\mu \xi_\nu + \nabla_\nu \xi_\mu = g_{\mu\alpha} \partial_\nu \xi^\alpha + g_{\nu\alpha} \partial_\mu \xi^\alpha + \xi^\alpha \partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}
$$
Then the quantity
$$
Q = \xi^\alpha u_\alpha
$$
is conserved along any geodesic. To see this, we can compute
$$
u^\alpha \nabla_\alpha Q = u^\alpha  u^\beta \nabla_\alpha \xi_\beta +  u^\alpha \nabla_\alpha u_\beta \xi^\beta
$$
The first term above is zero because I can symmetrize $\nabla_\alpha \xi_\beta \to \frac{1}{2} \left( \nabla_\alpha \xi_\beta + \nabla_\beta \xi_\alpha \right)$ which is then zero since $\xi$ is a Killing vector. The second term is zero due to the geodesic equation. Thus
$$
u^\alpha \nabla_\alpha Q  = 0
$$
Finally, we note that if the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ is independent of a particular coordinate $\phi$, then $K^\alpha = \delta^\alpha_\phi$ is a Killing vector. We can see this by simply plugging this into the Killing equation and we find
$$
g_{\mu\alpha} \partial_\nu K^\alpha + g_{\nu\alpha} \partial_\mu K^\alpha + K^\alpha \partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\phi g_{\mu\nu} = 0
$$
The first two terms vanish since $K$ is a constant. The last term vanishes by assumption.

Therefore, if the metric is independent of $\phi$, then $K^\alpha = \delta^\alpha_\phi$ is a Killing vector and
$$
Q = K^\alpha u_\alpha = u_\phi \propto p_\phi
$$
is a conserved quantity.